# Java (not so)Simple formatting

Tags: java, format

Hey guys so my homework was to:
1)Prompt the user to enter the number of cells C
2)Declare an integer array cell[] with C elements
3)Prompt the user to enter the number of time steps N
3)Prompt the user to enter the index of cells that contain 1(enter negative index to finish)
4)Run the cellular automaton for N time steps, using the rules defined above
5)On each time step, display the cells, printing a ‘#’ if the cell contains a 1, 
a space if the cell contains a 0

A desired output would be:

```
Enter number of cells (<= 80): 10
Enter number of time steps: 10 
Enter the index of occupied cells (negative index to end): 4 6 -1  
0123456789

    # #
   ####
  ##  #
 ### ##
 # ####
 ###  #
 # # ##
 ######
 #    #
 #   ##
 #  ###
```

My code so far is this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class P7{
    public static void main(String[] args){
       int i, N, C, index;
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.println("Enter number of cells(<=80):");
       C = in.nextInt();
       int[] cell = new int[C];
       System.out.println("Enter number of time steps:");
       N = in.nextInt();
       System.out.println("Enter the index of occupied cells(-num to end):");
       for(i = 0; i < C; i++){
          cell[i] = 0;
       }
       while(true){
          index = in.nextInt();

          if(index < 0){
             break;
          }
          cell[index] = 1;
       }
       for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
          updateCells(cell);
          displayCells(cell);
    }


    public static void updateCells(int array[]){
       int i;
       int[] temp = new int[array.length];
       for(i = 1; i < array.length - 1; i++){
          if(array[i]==1 && array[i-1]==1 && array[i+1]==1)
             temp[i] = 0;
          else if(array[i]==1 && array[i-1]==1 && array[i+1]==0)
             temp[i] = 1;
          else if(array[i]==0 && array[i-1]==1 && array[i+1]==1)
             temp[i] = 1;
          else if(array[i]==0 && array[i-1]==1 && array[i+1]==0)
             temp[i] = 0;
          else if(array[i]==1 && array[i-1]==0 && array[i+1]==1)
             temp[i] = 1;
          else if(array[i]==1 && array[i-1]==0 && array[i+1]==0)
             temp[i] = 1;
          else if(array[i]==0 && array[i-1]==0 && array[i+1]==1)
             temp[i] = 1;
          else if(array[i]==0 && array[i-1]==0 && array[i+1]==0)
             temp[i] = 0;
       }
       for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
          array[i] = temp[i];
       }
}
public static void displayCells(int data[]){
       int i;
       for(i=0;i < data.length; i++){
          if(data[i] == 1)
             System.out.println("#");
          else if(data[i] == 0)
             System.out.println(" ");
       }
   }
}
```

This is my current output:

```
Enter number of cells(<=80): 10
Enter number of time steps: 3
Enter the index of occupied cells(-num to end):
1
2
3
4
-1

#
#
#
#
```

Any and all help will be appreciated :D

Comment: `println` read the documentation for that function. Also, while you are there, look at the `print` function

Answer (score 0):

I actually don't understand what you trying to do, try this if that might would help. If you have the question in written or any pdf, then I can probably tell. Best

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class P7{
    public static void main(String[] args){
       int i, N, C, index;
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.println("Enter number of cells(<=80):");
       C = in.nextInt();
       int[] cell = new int[C];
       System.out.println("Enter number of time steps:");
       N = in.nextInt();
       System.out.println("Enter the index of occupied cells(-num to end):");
       for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
          cell[i] = 0;
       }
       while(true){
          index = in.nextInt();

          if(index < 0){
             break;
          }
          cell[index] = 1;
       }
       for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
          updateCells(cell);
          displayCells(cell);
    }
   public static void updateCells(int cell[]){
       int i;
       int[] temp = new int[cell.length];
       for(i = 1; i < cell.length - 1; i++){
          if(cell[i]==1 && cell[i-1]==1 && cell[i+1]==1)
             temp[i] = 0;
          else if(cell[i]==1 && cell[i-1]==1 && cell[i+1]==0)
             temp[i] = 1;
          else if(cell[i]==0 && cell[i-1]==1 && cell[i+1]==1)
             temp[i] = 1;
          else if(cell[i]==0 && cell[i-1]==1 && cell[i+1]==0)
             temp[i] = 0;
          else if(cell[i]==1 && cell[i-1]==0 && cell[i+1]==1)
             temp[i] = 1;
          else if(cell[i]==1 && cell[i-1]==0 && cell[i+1]==0)
             temp[i] = 1;
          else if(cell[i]==0 && cell[i-1]==0 && cell[i+1]==1)
             temp[i] = 1;
          else if(cell[i]==0 && cell[i-1]==0 && cell[i+1]==0)
             temp[i] = 0;
       }
       for(i = 0; i < cell.length; i++){
          cell[i] = temp[i];
       }
}
public static void displayCells(int cell[]){
       int i;
       for(i=0;i < cell.length; i++){
          if(cell[i] == 1)
             System.out.print("#");
          else if(cell[i] == 0)
             System.out.print(" ");
       }
   }
}`enter code here`
```